# confirmation email message without using membership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am using my own security system (custom authentication, authorization ...)

i just want to send confirmation email after user register how can i do this without membership tables ?

FYI:when i am build my own authorize system i just override AuthorizeCore function like this

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
}
```

is there any functions like AuthorizeCore  to confirm account or change password can override ?

appreciate any help thanks

Comment: What class is `AuthorizeCore` from?

Comment: AuthorizeAttribute class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No attribute can do this; you need to do this within the controller.  However, the default security framework does have API methods for this.  Since you have your own security, it makes sense to do this in the controller in a custom fashion.

Comment: can you help me Mr:Brain to do this in custom fashion (any link , article .... anything)

Comment: Sure, in your controller, use System.Net.Mail.  Here is a full tutorial on how to configure it.  You configure your message and send via an SMTP server.  See: http://www.systemnetmail.com/

Comment: really i am so grateful, the last question should confirmation link expired ? if yes or no why ?

Comment: Yes, for a week or two.  It's good to expire it just in case, as we are having accounts getting hacked all the time, it protects their account in case they were hacked; they could simply request the link again later.

Comment: thanks 
wish you happiness in this world and hereafter